# exec() command not working

Tags: php

I am using exec() function to run my commands on centos server. All was working fine untill i used command:
$command=
        **ffmpeg -i input video.mp4 -vf fade=out:0:5 output.mp4**

The command is ok as it is running on server via command line but when i execute it using php it is not giving the output. I have already created a video from ffmpeg using the exec() function but this command is not working. What can be the reason i am confused how a command can run on server but not work while executing from php.

Other command i executed using exec() function is :
$command = **ffmpeg -i %d.jpg -y -s 320x240 -aspect 4:3 output.mp4**

and it is working perfectly and the video is also created but previous command is not giving video as output.

Please guide me...

Comment: Could you copy/paste the exact PHP you're using? Quoting is important.

Comment: As is tagging the question with the language in use.

Comment: are you sure your input file name is called `input video.mp4`, with a space in the middle?

Comment: no there is no space. The actual command is: ffmpeg -i fade.mp4 -vf "fade=out:0:5" output.mp4. My exact php code is:$command= 'ffmpeg -i slideshow/frame1.mp4 -vf "fade=out:0:5" slideshow/fade1.mp4'  exec($command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging you command execution. For ffmpeg you need to pipe the output with `2>&1` to see it:

```
exec($command." 2>&1", $output);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: It is returning: string(37) "frame1.mp4: No such file or directory"
but frame1.mp4 is present at the location slideshow/. Why it is not able to find the file?

Comment: Try using the full path to the file and check the file permissions.

Comment: When i used the full file path with file permissions 777 i get:string(24) "Unrecognized option 'vf'" . What else i should use to refer to filters i also tried -vfilters but the same error comes...

Comment: -vf should work. Check out the [Doku](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html), looks ugly but helps a lot!